# How to parse an HTTP request with `gen_tcp`?

Tags: http, erlang

Below is part of one example explaining how to use `gen_tcp`. However, almost all of the tutorials will just show you an echo server, but none doing parsing of a real world HTTP request.

```
    handle_connect(Socket, BinaryList, Count) ->
    io:format("handle_connect ~p~n", [self()]),
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
    {ok, Binary} ->
        io:format("request is :~s~n", Binary),
        case gen_tcp:send(Socket, Binary) of
            ok ->
                handle_connect(Socket, BinaryList, Count);
            {error, Reason} ->
                io:format("send failed~n"),
                gen_tcp:close(Socket)
        end;
```

I am curious about how one can parse the data in Erlang that is received by [`gen_tcp:recv/\[2,3\]`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#recv-2). I skimmed through the code at `lib/inets-5.7.1/src/http_server` but there are too many modules, and I still can't figure out what the basics of parsing an HTTP request would be.

Can anyone show me how to parse an HTTP request, and what approach web frameworks take? Thanks~

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957164/erlang-gen-tcp-not-receiving-anything

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of lightweight web server libraries for Erlang including:

- [Cowboy](https://github.com/extend/cowboy)
- [MochiWeb](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb.git)
- [Misultin](https://github.com/ostinelli/misultin.git) (not maintained anymore)

There is also [Yaws](https://github.com/klacke/yaws.git) which is more comparable to Apache. I would recommend checking out the code of Cowboy since it is very modular.

A shortcut to answer your question might be found here:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#decode_packet-3 and 
[https://github.com/extend/cowboy/blob/master/src/cowboy_http_protocol.erl#L99](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/5d1cf363587870db7bb2333456d4c9d1b6ad1c5f/src/cowboy_http.erl#L341)