# Erlang client-server example using gen_tcp is not receiving anything

Tags: erlang, gen-tcp

I am trying to receive data at client side, but nothing is received.

Server code that sends message

```
client(Socket, Server) ->
  gen_tcp:send(Socket,"Please enter your name"),
  io:format("Sent confirmation"),
  {ok, N} = gen_tcp:recv(Socket,0),
  case string:tokens(N,"\r\n") of
    [Name] ->
      Client = #client{socket=Socket, name=Name, pid=self()},
      Server ! {'new client', Client},
      client_loop(Client, Server)
  end.
```

Client that should receive and print out

```erlang
client(Port)->
   {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:connect("localhost",Port,[{active,false},{packet,2}]),
   A = gen_tcp:recv(Sock,0),
   A.
```

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this? The posted code is missing the definition of several functions, the code that spawns the server and accepts connections, etc.

Comment: my code is basically this. http://www2.erlangcentral.org/wiki/?title=Chatserver Main work mechanics is the same, only difference is in the loop function, where i call some other functions to do stuff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your client is faulty because it specifies:

```
{packet, 2}
```

yet the server specifies (in code not shown) :

```
{packet, 0}
```

In `Programming Erlang (2nd)` on p. 269 it says:

> Note that the arguments to *packet* used by the client and the server
> *must agree*.  If the server was opened with `{packet,2}` and the client with `{packet,4}`, then nothing would work.

The following client can successfully receive text from the server:

```
%%=== Server:  {active,false}, {packet,0} ====

client(Port) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(
        localhost, 
        Port, 
        [{active,false},{packet,0}]
     ),

    {ok, Chunk} = gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0),
    io:format("Client received: ~s", [Chunk]),
    timer:sleep(1000),

    Name = "Marko",
    io:format("Client sending: ~s~n", [Name]),
    gen_tcp:send(Socket, Name),

    loop(Socket).

loop(Socket) ->
    {ok, Chunk} = gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0),
    io:format("Client received: ~s~n", [Chunk]),
    loop(Socket).
```

However, I think that both the chatserver and my client have ***serious issues***.  When you send a message through a TCP (or UDP) connection, you have to assume that the message will get split into an indeterminate number of chunks--each with an arbitrary length.  When `{packet,0}` is specified, I think `recv(Socket, 0)` will only read one chunk from the socket, then return.  That chunk *may* be the entire message, or it might be only a piece of the message.  To guarantee that you've read the entire message from the socket, I think you have to loop over the recv():

```
get_msg(Socket, Chunks) ->
    Chunk = gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0),
    get_msg(Socket, [Chunk|Chunks]).
```

Then the question becomes: how do you know when you've read the entire message so that you can end the loop?  `{packet,0}` tells Erlang not to prepend a length header to a message, so how do you know where the end of the message is?  Are more chunks coming, or did the recv() already read the last chunk?   I think the marker for the end of the message is when the other side closes the socket:

```
get_msg(Socket, Chunks) ->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        {ok, Chunk} ->
            get_msg(Socket, [Chunk|Chunks]);
        {error, closed} ->
            lists:reverse(Chunks);
        {error, Other} ->
            Other
    end.
```

But that raises another issue: if the chatserver is looping on a recv() waiting for a message from the client, and after the client sends a message to the server the client loops on a recv() waiting for a message from the server, and both sides need the other side to close the socket to break out of their recv() loops, then you will get deadlock because neither side is closing their socket. As a result, the client will have to close the socket in order for the chatserver to break out of its recv() loop and process the message.  But, then the server can't send() anything back to the client because the client closed the socket.  As a result, I don't know if you can do two way communication when `{packet,0}` is specified.

Here are my conclusions about `{packet, N}` and `{active, true|false}` from reading the docs and searching around:

---

**send()**:

When you call `send()`, no data* is actually transferred to the destination. Instead, `send()` blocks until the destination calls `recv()`, and only then is data transferred to the destination.

* In "Programming Erlang (2nd)", on p. 176 it says that a small amount of data will be pushed to the destination when you call `send()` due to the way an OS buffers data, and thereafer `send()` will block until a `recv()` pulls data to the destination.

---

**Default options**:

You can get the defaults for a socket by specifying an empty list for its options, then doing:

```
Defaults = inet:getopts(Socket, [mode, active, packet]),
io:format("Default options: ~w~n", [Defaults]).

--output:--
Default options: {ok,[{mode,list},{active,true},{packet,0}]}
```

You can use inet:getopts() to show that `gen_tcp:accept(Socket)` returns a socket with the same options as Socket.

---

---

```
                    {active, true}   {active,false}
                   +--------------+----------------+
{packet, 1|2|4}:   |    receive   |     recv()     |
                   |    no loop   |     no loop    |
                   +--------------+----------------+
{packet, 0|raw}:   |    receive   |     recv()     |
  (equivalent)     |    loop      |     loop       |
                   +--------------+----------------+
```

> #### {active, false}

Messages **do not** land in the mailbox.  This option is used to prevent clients from flooding a server's mailbox with messages.  Do not try to use a *receive block* to extract 'tcp' messages from the mailbox--there won't be any.  When a process wants to read a message, the process needs to read the message directly from the socket by calling `recv()`.

**{packet, 1|2|4}**:

The packet tuple specifies the *protocol* that each side expects messages to conform to.  `{packet, 2}` specifies that each message will be preceded by two bytes, which will contain the length of the message.  That way, a receiver of a message will know how long to keep reading from the stream of bytes to reach the end of the message.  When you send a message over a TCP connection, you have no idea how many chunks the message will get split into.  If the receiver stops reading after one chunk, it might not have read the whole message.  Therefore, the receiver needs an indicator to tell it when the whole message has been read.

With `{packet, 2}`, a receiver will read two bytes to get the length of the message, say 100, then the receiver will wait until it has read 100 bytes from the randomly sized chunks of bytes that are streaming to the receiver.

Note that when you call `send()`, erlang automatically calculates the number of bytes in the message and inserts the length into `N` bytes, as specified by `{packet, N}`, and appends the message.  Likewise, when you call `recv()` erlang automatically reads `N` bytes from the stream, as specified by `{packet, N}`, to get the length of the message, then `recv()` blocks until it reads length bytes from the socket, then `recv()` returns the whole message.

**{packet, 0 | raw}** (equivalent):

When `{packet, 0}` is specified, `recv()` will read the number of bytes specified by its Length argument.  If Length is 0, then I think `recv()` will read one chunk from the stream, which will be an arbitrary number of bytes.  As a result, the combination of `{packet, 0}` and `recv(Socket, 0)` requires that you create a loop to read all the chunks of a message, and the indicator for `recv()` to stop reading because it has reached the end of the message will be when the other side closes the socket:

```
get_msg(Socket, Chunks) ->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        {ok, Chunk} -> 
            get_msg(Socket, [Chunk|Chunks]);
        {error, closed} ->
            lists:reverse(Chunks);
        {error, Other} ->
            Other
    end.
```

Note that a sender cannot simply call `gen_tcp:close(Socket)` to signal that it is done sending data (see the description of [gen_tcp:close/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#close-1) in the docs).  Instead, a sender has to signal that is is done sending data by calling [gen_tcp:shutdown/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#shutdown-2).

I think the chatserver is faulty because it specifies `{packet, 0}` in combination with `recv(Socket, 0)`, yet it does not use a loop for the `recv()`:

```
client_handler(Sock, Server) ->
    gen_tcp:send(Sock, "Please respond with a sensible name.\r\n"),
    {ok,N} = gen_tcp:recv(Sock,0), %% <**** HERE ****
    case string:tokens(N,"\r\n") of
```

---

> #### {active, true}

Messages sent through a TCP (or UDP) connection are automatically read from the socket for you and placed in the *controlling process*'s mailbox. The controlling process is the process that called accept() or the process that called connect().  Instead of calling recv() to read messages directly from the socket, you extract messages from the mailbox with a *receive block*:

```
get_msg(Socket)
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Chunk} ->  %Socket is already bound!
        ...
    end
```

**{packet, 1|2|4}**:

Erlang automatically reads all the chunks of a message from the socket for you and places a complete message (with the length header stripped off) in the mailbox:

```
get_msg(Socket) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, CompleteMsg} ->
            CompleteMsg,
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("Server closed socket.~n")
    end.
```

**{packet, 0 | raw}** (equivalent):

Messages will not have a length header, so when Erlang reads from the socket, Erlang has no way of knowing when the end of the message has arrived.  As a result, Erlang places each chunk it reads from the socket into the mailbox.  You need a loop to extract all the chunks from the mailbox, and the other side has to close the socket to signal that no more chunks are coming:

```
get_msg(ClientSocket, Chunks) ->
    receive
        {tcp, ClientSocket, Chunk} ->
            get_msg(ClientSocket, [Chunk|Chunks]);
        {tcp_closed, ClientSocket} ->
            lists:reverse(Chunks)
    end.
```

---

---

The `recv()` [docs](http://erldocs.com/current/kernel/gen_tcp.html?i=0&search=gen_tcp:recv#recv/2) mention something about `recv()`'s Length argument *only* being applicable to sockets in *raw* mode. But because I don't know when a Socket is in raw mode, I don't trust the Length argument. But see here: [Erlang gen_tcp:recv(Socket, Length) semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778546/erlang-gen-tcprecvsocket-length-semantics).  Okay, now I'm getting somewhere: from the erlang [inet docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html):

```ruby
{packet, PacketType}(TCP/IP sockets)
Defines the type of packets to use for a socket. Possible values:

raw | 0
    No packaging is done.

1 | 2 | 4
    Packets consist of a header specifying the number of bytes in the packet, followed by that  
    number of bytes. The header length can be one, two, or four bytes, and containing an  
    unsigned integer in big-endian byte order. Each send operation generates the header, and the  
    header is stripped off on each receive operation.

    The 4-byte header is limited to 2Gb [message length].
```

As the examples at [Erlang gen_tcp:recv(Socket, Length) semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778546/erlang-gen-tcprecvsocket-length-semantics) confirm, when `{packet,0}` is specified, a `recv()` can specify the Length to read from the TCP stream.

Comment: Thank you! Such a silly mistake :). Erlang seems better and better with every thing i do in it.

Comment: You explaination is very straitforward. I am looking for option {packet, size} and saw your comment.