# Java / Erlang: Diffie Hellman Key Exchange not Working

Tags: java, erlang, x509, diffie-hellman

I wanted to implement my own encryption for my application. I did a major overhaul of this post. I really didn't have much time until today to address it. Hopefully this being the more useful than my original. Spent a ridiculous amount of time on this issue. Hopefully can save others that time.

I encountered several issues while doing this. I did not realize what was happening until the very end. I was getting different shared secrets and later some exceptions.

This is what I tried:

- Used the built in facilities provided by both languages. Couldn't figure out how to get the raw public key into a form Java could use.
- Scratched that and went with the simple formulas to calculate the public and private keys for each party. (This statistically could've worked ~25% of the time... luckily for me it didn't.)
- Dived into ASN.1 documentation from the ITU and sent the Erlang public key encoded in a similar manner to Java's keys. Determined this by saving the Java key to a file and using a hex editor. I didn't go back and test at great length. It did get rid of `java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification`. Think statistics didn't work in my favor here either. The secrets still did not match.
- Sent all numbers from Java to the Erlang-side to compute keys, shared secret using Java numbers... Same numbers. There is hope!!!
- Started carefully examining the data they were communicating. This was a bit time consuming as Erlang has the data organized in unsigned bytes. The Eclipse IDE (maybe there's a setting somewhere to change) uses signed bytes in byte arrays and a signed integer array within `BigInteger`.

This is where I began to see things. This all was manually entered over many iterations to make sure I found the correct pattern of events. In Erlang I see my public key beginning with `<<215, 101, 208, 153,`. The first element of the `BigInteger` on the Java-side is `681193318`. The buffer the byte data was read into reads: `[-41, 101, -48, -103`. (Same as Erlang's). However taking the time convert the 1st four elements of the binary string to an integer...

`<<I:32/signed-integer>> = <<215,101,208,153>>.`

That yields `-681193319` versus the big integer's `681193318`

The code I was using was some what simple:

Erlang "Server":

```
-module(echo).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    crypto:start(),
    spawn(fun () -> {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:listen(12321, [binary, {packet, raw}]),
    echo_loop(Sock)
    end).

echo_loop(Sock) ->
    {ok, Conn} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),
    io:format("Got connection: ~p~n", [Conn]),
    Handler = spawn(fun () -> handle(Conn) end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Conn, Handler),
    echo_loop(Sock).

p() ->
    16#ffffffffffffffffc90fdaa22168c234c4c6628b80dc1cd129024e088a67cc74020bbea63b139b22514a08798e3404ddef9519b3cd3a431b302b0a6df25f14374fe1356d6d51c245e485b576625e7ec6f44c42e9a637ed6b0bff5cb6f406b7edee386bfb5a899fa5ae9f24117c4b1fe649286651ece65381ffffffffffffffff.

g() ->
    2.

handle(Conn) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Conn, Yc} ->
            Xs = crypto:strong_rand_bytes(64),
            Ys = crypto:mod_pow(g(),Xs,p()),
            S = crypto:mod_pow(Yc, Xs, p()),

            AESKey = crypto:hash(sha256, S),

            gen_tcp:send(Conn, Ys),%KeyCert),
            handle(Conn);
        {tcp_closed, Conn} ->
            io:format("Connection closed: ~p~n", [Conn])
    end.
```

Java "Client":

```
public class MyProgram {
    private static Socket s;
    private static OutputStream out;
    private static InputStream in;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MessageDigest hash;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        byte buf2[];
        int len = 0;
        byte[] aeskey;

        try {
            hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte    keybuffer[] = new byte[64];
            SecureRandom srnd = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            BigInteger Xc, Yc, Sc, Ys;

            srnd.nextBytes(keybuffer);
            Xc = new BigInteger(keybuffer);
            Yc = new BigInteger("2").modPow(Xc, DiffieHellman.Group2.P);

            s = new Socket("localhost",12321);
            out = s.getOutputStream();
            in = s.getInputStream();

            out.write(Yc.toByteArray());
            out.flush();

            len = in.read(buffer);
            buf2 = new byte[len];
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, buf2, 0, len);

            Ys = new BigInteger(buf2);          
            Sc = Ys.modPow(Xc, DiffieHellman.Group2.P);
            aeskey = hash.digest(Sc.toByteArray());

            out.close();
            in.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

What was wrong?

Comment: When you send data over a socket, you have no way of knowing how many chunks it will get split into.  When you specify `{packet, raw}` ( or equivalently `{packet, 0}` ), you are telling erlang that you will take care of assembling the indeterminate number of chunks into the complete data, so  erlang just puts each chunk into a separate message.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957164/erlang-gen-tcp-not-receiving-anything.  I don't know if the above is causing any of your problems, but it is something you need to address.

Comment: @7stud Thanks. Easy enough to change. I thought though that TCP would handle that. TCP should be at the highest implemented in OS I believe. I noticed two things however. **1)** The key is transmitted correctly (only 128 bytes) **2)** When I use `{packet, 2}` I think erlang maybe expecting something that I didn't provide in my Java app and hangs indefinitely. I used `1` and that resulted in a successful transmission but the keys were 1-byte longer on the Java-side. More stuff to manage.

Comment: *I thought though that TCP would handle that*.  I think TCP handles splitting a chunk into packets to send and then reassembling the packets into a chunk on the receiving end--but the number of chunks your data gets split into is determined by the state of the *network buffers*.  Read this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667903/python-socket-receive-large-amount-of-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is reading but not understanding the documentation. I spend a lot of time in reference pages because I don't code very often. I did not think much of this particular detail in the documentation for `BigInteger`:

> All operations behave as if Bigintegers were represented in
>   **two's-complement notation**...

There are two spots in my original code where this presents an issue:

```
       Ys = new BigInteger(buf2);          
       Sc = Ys.modPow(Xc, DiffieHellman.Group2.P);
```

The issue with the first line is that if bit 8 is set in the first byte the entire `buf2` array needs to be prepended with a `0x00` byte. There is an issue with the second line as well... it does not become evident until the following line is executed: `aeskey = hash.digest(Sc.toByteArray());`

The issue here is if bit 8 is set in the first byte of the result... `0x00` is prepended to it. This is forwarded to the `digest()` function but needs to be omitted.

My code changed to what is below and works: :)

```
    len = in.read(buffer);
    buf2 = new byte[len+1];
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, buf2, 1, len);
    buf2[0] = 0;

    if(buf2[1] < 0)
        Ys = new BigInteger(buf2);
    else
        Ys = new BigInteger(Arrays.copyOfRange(buf2, 1, buf2.length));

    Sc = Ys.modPow(Xc, DiffieHellman.Group2.P);
    buffer = Sc.toByteArray();
    if(buffer[0] == 0)
        aeskey = hash.digest(Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 1, buffer.length));
    else
        aeskey = hash.digest(buffer);
```

These two lines were left as is:

```
    Xc = new BigInteger(keybuffer);
    Yc = new BigInteger("2").modPow(Xc, DiffieHellman.Group2.P);
```

This is because the private key can be "any random number." The `0x00` byte is prepended if necessary to the public key of the client in the second line. However Erlang interprets integers as big-endian and any leading `0x00` bytes end up being irrelevant as it does not affect the numerical value and hence the result when conducting a `crypto:mod_pow()`.

Comments on how to improve code very welcome.