# How handle only one client simultaneously in erlang gen_tcp?

Tags: tcp, erlang, tcplistener, gen-tcp

I have TCP server that listen Ip:Port.

```
listen(Ip, Port) ->
  Opts = [
    binary,
    {active, false},
    {packet, 0},
    {reuseaddr, true},
    {ip, Ip}
  ],

  case gen_tcp:listen(Port, Opts) of
    {ok, ListenSock} ->
      ?MODULE:loop_accept(ListenSock);
    {error, Reason} ->
      exit(Reason)
  end.

loop_accept(ListenSock) ->
  {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSock),
  ?MODULE:loop(Sock),
  ?MODULE:loop_accept(ListenSock).

loop(Sock) ->
  case gen_tcp:recv(Sock, 0) of
    {ok, Data} ->
      gen_tcp:send(Sock, [<<"Response: ">>, Data]),
      ?MODULE:loop(Sock);

    {error, Reason} ->
      ok
  end.
```

Task: when one client connected on Ip:Port (for example `telnet Ip Port`), another client trying connection must be dropped. In other words, exclusive usage of Ip:Port.

Questions:

- How it's implement on Erlang using gen_tcp module?
- It is possible resolve by options of gen_tcp:listen?
- How to programmaticaly drop trying connection in Erlang?

P.S. I am new in erlang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can't `recv()` like that when you specify `{packet, 0}`.  Read this [answer about gen_tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43959020/926143).

The server could:

1. `Pid = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [Sock])`
2. Monitor the process in #1:

   ```
   Ref = monitor(process, Pid)
   ```

   But to prevent a race condition, you should perform #1 and #2 in one step:

   ```
   {Pid, Ref} = spawn_monitor(?MODULE, loop [Sock])
   ```
3. After `gen_tcp:accept(ListenSock)` executes, do:

   ```
   gen_tcp:close(ListenSock)
   ```
4. Detect when the client terminates and therefore it's time to start listening for a new client:

   ```
   receive {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, _Reason} -> 
   listen(Ip, Port)
   ```

   Or, if the client will not terminate after it is done sending data, then you can detect when the client closes the socket in `loop()`:

   ```
    case gen_tcp:recv(Sock, 0) of
        {ok, Data} ->
            gen_tcp:send(Sock, [<<"Response: ">>, Data]),
            ?MODULE:loop(Sock);

        {error, closed} ->
            listen(Ip, Port);

        {error, Reason} ->
             ok
     end
   ```

=====

**backlog** socket option (e.g. `{backlog, 0}`):

The backlog option sets an OS socket configuration parameter.  From `man listen`:

> The backlog parameter defines the maximum length for the queue of
>   pending connections.  If a connection request arrives with the queue
>   full, the client ***may*** receive an error with an indication of
>   ECONNREFUSED.  Alternatively, if the underlying protocol supports
>   retransmission, the request may be ignored so that retries may
>   succeed.

And, a good read is this thread at Perl Monks: [TCP server: How to reject connections when busy?](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=940662)  Some snippets about the *backlog* configuration:

> So, it looks like connection request are just ignored (as TCP does
>   support retransmission)
>
> ...when the queue is full, then the system simply stops answering SYN
>   packets, which triggers their resending. As result, the peer gets no
>   indication that your server is busy. It simply keeps waiting for
>   connection to be established.

Comment: Thanks for reply and link to another answer! I attempted using `backlog` option but it did not work as I expected. Please can you tell me why?

Comment: @Meatbot, See reply at bottom of my answer.