# Unable to receive TCP packets using erlangs `:socket` module

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, erlang, elixir

I am attempting to receive all TCP packets using low-level sockets via erlangs `:socket` module:

```
def start() do
  {:ok, socket} = :socket.open(:inet, :raw, :tcp)
  recv(socket)
end

defp recv(socket) do
  :socket.recv(socket) |> IO.inspect()
  recv(socket)
end
```

But no packets are received. Using `:socket.open(:inet, :raw, :ip)` works and receives packets. Binding via `:socket.bind/2` (e.g. `:socket.bind(socket, :any)` or other variations) doesn't help either. I am running the functions as root as well. Is there any specific configuration needed to capture TCP packets? How can I capture all TCP packets?

I know about third-party packages, such as [procket](https://github.com/msantos/procket), but would like to use the `:sockets` module.

(Using MacOS, but doesn't work on Linux either).

Comment: Do you know about `gen_tcp`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957164/erlang-client-server-example-using-gen-tcp-is-not-receiving-anything

Comment: How do you send packets to that socket?

Comment: @7stud yes but I wanted to use raw sockets instead of `:gen_tcp`. @Aetherus I got it to work on Linux after all. I also changed from just listening to TCP to listening to all ethernet packets and then remove headers to get TCP payloads.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me on my Linux box.

```
% elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Elixir 1.12.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)
```